# The mapping cant instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [AddServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [AddServlet]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:881)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AddServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:881)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Comment: Do you have a class named `AddServlet` in the default package?

Comment: Where did you place the   AddServlet.class  file?

Comment: Do not use the default package: classes inside packages can not access it.

Comment: Please read [ask]: Just dumping an error message does not make a proper question. Please give steps to reproduce, ideally in the form of a [mcve] and mention the _exact_ version that you're using